# Synchronized Block inside run method

Tags: java, multithreading

If I have something like below, so what does that mean inside `synchronized block`

```
synchronised (syncObject) {
```

Basically, it will means only one thread can be inside the above block and as soon as one thread is finished executing, second thread will enter that synchronized block **synchronised (syncObject)**. Right?
Can anyone explain to me in a LayMan language so that I can get better picture?

```
private static final class Task implements Runnable {
{
  private static Object syncObject = new Object();

    public Task(Command command, BlockingQueue<Integer> pool1, BlockingQueue<Integer> pool2) {
    this.command = command;
    this.existPool = pool1;
    this.newPool = pool2;
}

  public void run()
  {
    synchronised (syncObject) {
      if() {
        existId = existPool.take();
        attributeMethod(existId);
        } else if() {
            newId = newPool.take();
            attributeMethod(newId);
        }
    }
  }
}

// So I need to make this method synchronized or not? Currently I have made this synchronized
private synchronized void attributeMethod(int range) {
    // And suppose If I am calling any other method here-

 sampleMethod();
}


// What about this method, I need to make this synchronized as well? or not?
private synchronized void sampleMethod() {


}
```

Comment: Note that there was also one more answer, [posted as edit to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1869171). (See green highlighting on the right side)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Basically, it will means only one thread can be inside the above block and as soon as one thread is finished executing, second thread will enter that synchronized block synchronised (syncObject). Right?

Right!

> So I need to make this method synchronized or not?

No you don't.  Assuming that the method is only going to be called from within the synchronized block in the `run()` method, that block will already prevent multiple threads from executing the method simultaneously.  So declaring the method to be `synchronized` is redundant.

However, I should point out some things:

- When you declare an instance method as `synchronized`, it will synchronize on `this`; i.e. on the `Task` object.  But your `synchronized` block is synchronizing on a different object ... the object in `syncObject`.  In this case, this doesn't matter.  However, if the `synchronized` block in the `run()` method wasn't there, you would find that the threads were attempting synchronizing on different objects ... and you would NOT get mutual exclusion.
- By synchronizing at the top level of the `run()` method ... using a single shared `syncObject` for all threads that execute that task ... you are effectively making the tasks run one at a time.  This completely negates any benefits of using threads.
- It is good practice to declare the variable containing a private lock object (such as `syncObject`) to be `final`.  This avoids the possibility that something might overwrite it ... resulting in a synchronization failure.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, Really Appreciated your help in making me understand the simple stuff. I just posted [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047464/synchronized-method-outside-the-run-method) which similar to the above one but as you said in your seocnd point, If I put synchronize at the top level of the run() method, I am negating the benefits of threads. So that is the reason I was thinking to change the logic and see if I am correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

No, `attributeMethod` is already running within the scope of a `synchronized` block; no need to mark it as such, unless you intend to call it concurrently outside this block.

Comment: Thanks Joao for the suggestion and what about my first question? `Basically, it will means only one thread can be inside that block and as soon as one thread is finished executing, second thread will enter that synchronized block. Right?
` Am I right? After one thread has finished executing that block, then only second thread will enter into that right?

Comment: And for my second question, I can have multiple methods without the synchronized keyword inside that block `synchronised (syncObject) {` right? So only one thread will be in that block and as soon as first thread has finished executing it, second thread will come enter into that block and execute all those methods that are there in that synchronized block right?

Comment: Yes, only one thread may enter a `synchronized` block at a time, all other threads get suspended until the first thread is done.

Comment: Thanks Joao, I just updated my question with one additional thing, that I wanted to ask. Suppose If I have another method `sampleMethod`, so that `sampleMethod` also will not be synchronized right? As you said it will be in the scope of a synchronized block?

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't matter how many call hierarchies you add, other threads will suspend their execution when they reach the `synchronized` block while `syncObject` is currently locked by another  thread.

Comment: Thanks Joao, Really Appreciated your help in making me understand the simple stuff. I just posted [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047464/synchronized-method-outside-the-run-method) which similar to the above one. Just wanted to understand this part as well, which is just the opposite of the above question.