# Synchronized method outside the run method

Tags: java, multithreading

This question is follow up on this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047218/synchronized-block-inside-run-method), Similar question but the execution is different, As In the below code, I don't have any lock on the object. So trying to understand clearly, I am right or not.

**What I understand so far through reading the books and articles:-**

Each Thread will enter the `run method`, and will get the `id from the various pool (existPool or newPool)` depending on `if, else if block`, then it will go into `attributeMethod` which has to be `synchronized` right? And there is another method in that `attributeMethod` which doesn't needs to be synchronized right?

So suppose if second thread also launch at the same time, so I will be having any problem with the below example?

```
private static final class Task implements Runnable {

    private BlockingQueue<Integer> existPool;
    private BlockingQueue<Integer> newPool;
    private int existId;
    private int newId;
    private Service service;

    public Task(Service service, BlockingQueue<Integer> pool1, BlockingQueue<Integer> pool2) {
        this.service = service;
        this.existPool = pool1;
        this.newPool = pool2;
    }
    public void run()  {
      if(service.getCriteria.equals("Previous")) {
          existId = existPool.take();
          attributeMethod(existId);
        } else if(service.getCriteria.equals("New")) {
            newId = newPool.take();
            attributeMethod(newId);
        }
    }
}


    // So I need to make this method synchronized or not? Currently I have made this synchronized
    private synchronized void attributeMethod(int range) {
        // And suppose If I am calling any other method here-

         sampleMethod();
    }

    // What about this method, I don't thinkg so, it will be synchronized as well as it will be in the scope of previous synchronized method whoever is calling, Right? or not?
    private void sampleMethod() {


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> So suppose if second thread also launch at the same time, so I will be having any problem with the below example?

Potentially, yes you will.  Reread the second bullet point in my answer to your previous question.

Basically, the problem is that the threads will each synchronize on a *different* instance of the `Task` class ... and that won't provide any mutual exclusion.

Whether this is *actually* a problem here will depend on whether the threads *need* to synchronize.  In this case, it appears that the threads will be sharing `Service` and `BlockingQueue` instances.  If that is the extent of their sharing AND you are using thread-safe implementation classes, then synchronization *may* not be necessary.

---

My advice to you would be go back to your Java textbook(s) / tutorial(s), and review what they say about what `synchronized` and primitive mutexes *actually* do.  They are really quite simple ... but you need to fully understand the primitives before you can put them together correctly to achieve the goal you are trying to achieve.